# Filter an array based on another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I am trying to use Underscore to filter an array based on matches in another array.

I have an array chartOptions.series which looks like this

```
[{category: "A"}, {category: "B"}, {category: "C"}]
```

I want to filter this array so that I keep only elements that exist in another array called categoryNames, which looks like this

```
[0: "A", 1: "B"]
```

Given this scenario I would expect this result

```
[{category: "A"}, {category: "B"}]
```

Here's what I have so far

```
chartOptions.series = _.filter(chartOptions.series, function(series) {
   return _.where(categoryNames, {"": series.category});
});
```

This doesn't work, it doesn't filter anything.  What am I missing?

Comment: `[{"A"}, {"B"}]` is syntactically invalid. How does it really look? Use `JSON.stringify()` on it if you're not sure.

Comment: `[{"A"}, {"B"}]` its invalid. ?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `[0: "A", 1: "B"]` is actually `["A", "B"]`, you can use `_.contains`:

```
var categoryNames = ["A", "B"];
_.filter(chartOptions.series, function(series) { 
  return _.contains(categoryNames, series.category) 
});
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to replace `contains` to `categoryNames.indexOf(series.category) >= 0` for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

More modern javascript:

```
chartOptions.series.filter(series => categoryNames.includes(series.category))
```